# How to integrate this function in correct way?

Tags: bivariate-distributions

I got an exercise on my class about bivariat distribution.
Given
$f(x,y)= x+y \quad \text{for} \quad 0<x<1, 0<y<1\\
f(x,y)= 0 \quad \text{for other.}\\$
Find $P[X+Y \leq \frac{3}{2}]$.

I tried to find that by drawn the graphic first. Then this is the graphic.

[image: this is the plot]

After that, I evaluated the value of $P[X+Y \leq \frac{3}{2}]$ used two different ways and it gave two different values, too. 
My first value is $P[X+Y \leq \frac{3}{2}]=\frac{23}{24}$
The second value is $P[X+Y \leq \frac{3}{2}]=\frac{19}{24}$.

Which one is correct? My first value or the second value?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: $P(X+Y \leq \frac  3 2)=\int_{1/2}^{1}\int_0^{3/2-y} (x+y) dx dy+\int_0^{1/2}\int_0^{1} (x+y) dx dy$.

Comment: @Kabo Murphy it's $\frac{19}{24}$, okay, thank you..